# Deleting axvline from the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi :) How can I delete an axvline that was created without assigning it to a variable? When it was assigned to a variable it can be deleted this way:

```
line = plt.axvline(x)
line.remove()
```

but how can I delete it when it was created like this (without assigning to a variable):

```
plt.axvline(x)
```

Comment: What else do have in the plot? Mind posting an image?

Comment: `plt.gca().lines[0].remove()` would remove the first line object of the plot. `plt.gca().lines[-1].remove()` the last.

Comment: I love you <3 <3